# Any Internet tools for viewing graphs of functions?

Tags: reference-request, graphing-functions, online-resources

I am looking for some Internet site where I can view correct and accurate graphs if I specify a formula for a function.

One such site is [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Any others and more suitable ones please?

Comment: Geogebra, Wolfram Alpha ,other CAS .

Comment: MSE has a sister site to do with Mathmatica: See, for example, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123977/branch-cut-of-sqrtx2-1

Comment: If only we had a website that could search the web for websites with keywords.

Comment: I read your bio. Did you mean to ask for a website, which allows configurations for the plot, like making it appear thicker? I would understand if the usual tools were hard to use for visually impeared people, as the graph in its entirety may be drawn rather thin...